# How to make a clickable cell in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I am using Data Table from CSS- bootstrap 4 data tables https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4

Please look at the image

[image]

The Row is clickable and it redirects me to another page1. BUT when I click on Find Location button, it does redirect me on page1 and page2 as well. I just want to go to page2. The code is below

index.php

```
  <tr onclick="xdata(this)">
                
    <td ><?php echo $event->description ? $event->description->type : null; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $event->description ? $event->description->text : null; ?></td>                
    <td><?php echo $event->origin && $event->origin->time? $event->origin->time->value: null; ?></td> 
                
    <form method="get" action="findLocation.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="LongitudeValue" value="<?php echo $event->origin && $event->origin->longitude? $event->origin->longitude->value : null; ?>" />
                
<td><input type="submit" value="FIND LOCATION" style="margin: auto;  width: 100%;  border: 3px solid green;  padding: 1px;" /></td>
</form>
</td>
```

app.js

```
function xdata(e){
    
     // Shows how to get data from each column of this row
    c2 = e.children.item(1).innerHTML;  
   // open new page
  window.open('indexXML_SEARCH.php?SearchValue='+c2, '_blank');
}
```

HOW can I click my findLocation button without it redirecting me to page1 but to page2 because whenever I press the button it opens a new window for page1 and the current page is redirected to page2. I just want page2 when button is clicked.

Note that when I click on the row (not the button) everything works fine whereby the page1 must be loaded that is open in a new window!

```
I am reading from XML and displaying thus, this is the code:
I cannot merge both code in One line for example: 

if this php echo $event->origin && $event->origin->quality? HAS 
SOMETHING!!, it returns $event->origin->quality->usedPhaseCount ELSE 
null

<td><?php echo $event->origin && $event->origin->quality?  $event- 
>origin->quality->usedPhaseCount: null; ?></td>


I want it The input button below to be in the second condition :
<td><input onclick="func1(event)" type="submit" value="FIND LOCATION" 
style="margin: auto;  width: 100%;  border: 3px solid green;  padding: 
1px;" /></td>


What I want But Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "<"

<td><?php echo $event->origin && $event->origin->quality? 
<input onclick="func1(event)" type="submit" value="FIND LOCATION" 
style="margin: auto;  width: 100%;  border: 3px solid green;  padding: 
1px;" />: null; ?></td>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: No need for PHP here. Please post rendered HTML, but first search for bootstrap datatables click row OR cell

Comment: @mplungjan I can click a row(open page1), it works fine BUT when I click the button it does two thing(open page1 and page2) because it is in the same row.. How to solve that ??

Comment: That's because the click even from your "Find location" button is bubbling up to the `<tr>` element. You need to stop the click event from propagating using` event.stopPropagation`

Comment: @karna - Can you [edit] your question to follow the guidance suggested by @mplungjan? (Your comment just repeats information which is already in the question.)

Comment: remove the 'type=submit' from your button. The default behaviour of submit re-loads the page. Alternatively, establish an event listener for the button and include `event.preventDefault()` inside it. I don't think you need a button at all, a styled div would do with an associated click listener.

Comment: Better change to type=button than remove the type

Comment: @mplungjan, I will make sure to take a tour, thank you for your msg.

Comment: @Terry, thank you sir, now it works completely fine by using on the button ...<td><input onclick="func1(event)" type="submit" value="FIND LOCATION" style="margin: auto;  width: 100%;  border: 3px solid green;  padding: 1px;" /></td>   AND SCRIPT TAG function func1(event) {
 
    event.stopPropagation();
 
}

Comment: Your HTML is invalid for a start. `form` is not a valid child of `tr`. It should be fully encapsulated in the `td` tag

Comment: @Terry, thank you sir.. please consider this last question. Its in the last paragraph. thank you for your time and consideration. starting with I am reading from XML and displaying thus, this is the code:

Answer (score 0):

The code is not clear and complete. However, I presume that you have defined onclick events for both `<tr>` and `<td>` tags and when you click the `<td>`, it also triggers the `<tr>` event. To prevent this, add this code at the end of your `<td>` event handler.

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: I have a click event on the button ...<td><input onclick="func1(event)" type="submit" value="FIND LOCATION" style="margin: auto; width: 100%; border: 3px solid green; padding: 1px;" /></td> AND SCRIPT TAG function func1(event) { event.stopPropagation();     //It works fine but is it good programming ??

Comment: yes, that is the purpose of stopPropagation()

Comment: thank you sir.. please consider this last question. Its in the last paragraph. thank you for your time and consideration. starting with I am reading from XML and displaying thus, this is the code:

Comment: It looks like an issue with the XML file, please check your xml file.